# How does the event translation work in a Giraffe router?

Tags: backbone.js, giraffe.js

I just discovered the approach to [router events in Giraffe](http://barc.github.io/backbone.giraffe/routersAndAppEvents.html). It is possible to trigger application events as follows:

```
  routes: {
    'childView/:name': 'route:childView'
    // 'someHashLocation/:andItsParams': 'some:appEvent'
  },
```

Since normally routing events are processed by callback functions, I wonder what does it take to trigger these routing events from a non-Giraffe Backbone application? Any issues that you see with this kind decoupling the router from application modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since normally routing events are processed by callback functions, I
>   wonder what does it take to trigger these routing events from a
>   non-Giraffe Backbone application?

Anything with a reference to a router can `cause` routing events, e.g.:

```
var app = new Giraffe.App({routes: {'post/:id': 'route:post'}});

// Trigger a route with an app reference
app.router.cause('route:post', 42); // => location changes to #post/42
                                    // => 'route:post' triggered on `app`
```

`Giraffe.Router#cause` is like `Backbone.Events#trigger` with the addition of navigating to the corresponding route, if one exists, and the `router` triggers the event on the `app`, not itself.

Anything with the app reference can listen for a routing event:

```
// Handle the route from outside the Giraffe app
app.on('route:post', function(id) {...});

// Other `Backbone.Events` instances can listen to the Giraffe app
var myOtherApp = new Backbone.View;
myOtherApp.listenTo(app, 'route:post', function(id) {...});
```

The app also acts as a convenient event hub beyond routing events. All Giraffe objects have a reference to `this.app` (if one has been created) and support for the shortcut `appEvents` bindings.

> Any issues that you see with this kind decoupling the router from application modules?

(I'm one of the authors) We at our company and I in my personal experience have not found this to be a problem, but one can imagine situations where this event-based system fails to provide the level of coordination needed. We've considered improving route handling with functionality like filters but haven't found the time for it yet. If you have suggestions we'd love to hear them!

Comment: thanks! together with http://modeln.github.io/backbone.geppetto/examples/ --> I got quite some new insights on an event driven architecture